# Преобразование комментария в ответ

Tags: предложение, комментарии, ответы

Заметил что многие верно отвечают в комментариях вместо полноценного ответа, может быть стесняются, может ещё что - не суть, сделайте пожалуйста функцию преобразования комментария в ответ, желательно чтобы и комментирующий это мог сделать и вопрошающий. Например 2 кнопочки "Преобразовать в ответ" и "Преобразовать в ответ и отметить решением".

Comment: Кстати, когда-то такая функция (преобразовать в ответ) была.